# PHP change Array key value to multiple keys and values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There is a serialized and un-serialized multi-dimensional array below. I am trying to explode the value of every key named "id" within this arry into four new keys...

```
$array_seril = 'a:9:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:42:"about.php///About Us///About Us///About US";}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:37:"products.php?la=men///Men///Men///Men";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:86:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing///All Clothing///All Clothing///Men : All Clothing";s:8:"children";a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:159:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear///Winter & Seasonal Wear///Winter & Seasonal Wear///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear";s:8:"children";a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:150:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Jackets///Jackets///Jackets///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Jackets";}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:174:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Thermal-Pants///Thermal Pants///Thermal Pants///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Thermal Pants";}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:184:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Suits-AnD-Blazers///Suits & Blazers///Suits & Blazers///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Suits & Blazers";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:189:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Suits-AnD-Blazers&le=Blazers///Blazers///Blazers///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Suits & Blazers : Blazers";}}}}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:89:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Other///Other///Other///Men : All Clothing : Other";}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:93:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Shirts///Shirts///Shirts///Men : All Clothing : Shirts";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:140:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Shirts&ld=Formal-Shirts///Formal Shirts///Formal Shirts///Men : All Clothing : Shirts : Formal Shirts";}}}i:3;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:113:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear///Sports Wear///Sports Wear///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear";s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:142:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Track-Pants///Track Pants///Track Pants///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Track Pants";}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:122:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Shorts///Shorts///Shorts///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Shorts";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:141:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Shorts&le=Sports///Sports///Sports///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Shorts : Sports";}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:137:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Shorts&le=Other///Other///Other///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Shorts : Other";}}}i:2;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:133:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=TDaShShirts///T-Shirts///T-Shirts///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : T-Shirts";}i:3;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:118:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Other///Other///Other///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Other";}}}i:4;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:89:"products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Jeans///Jeans///Jeans///Men : All Clothing : Jeans";}}}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:70:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear///Footwear///Footwear///Men : Footwear";s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:109:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Casual-Shoes///Casual Shoes///Casual Shoes///Men : Footwear : Casual Shoes";}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:85:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Sports///Sports///Sports///Men : Footwear : Sports";}i:2;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:141:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Sandals-and-Floaters///Sandals and Floaters///Sandals and Floaters///Men : Footwear : Sandals and Floaters";}i:3;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:145:"products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Slippers-and-FlipFlop///Slippers and FlipFlop///Slippers and FlipFlop///Men : Footwear : Slippers and FlipFlop";}}}}}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:45:"products.php?la=women///Women///Women///Women";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:86:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear///Ethnic Wear///Ethnic Wear///Women : Ethnic Wear";s:8:"children";a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:91:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Other///Other///Other///Women : Ethnic Wear : Other";}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:137:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Kurtas-AnD-Kurties///Kurtas & Kurties///Kurtas & Kurties///Women : Ethnic Wear : Kurtas & Kurties";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:140:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Kurtas-AnD-Kurties&ld=Kurties///Kurties///Kurties///Women : Ethnic Wear : Kurtas & Kurties : Kurties";}}}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:127:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms///Ethnic Bottoms///Ethnic Bottoms///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:150:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Harem-Pants///Harem Pants///Harem Pants///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Harem Pants";}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:180:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Patialas-AnD-Salwars///Patialas & Salwars///Patialas & Salwars///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Patialas & Salwars";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:179:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Patialas-AnD-Salwars&le=Salwars///Salwars///Salwars///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Patialas & Salwars : Salwars";}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:183:"products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Patialas-AnD-Salwars&le=Patialas///Patialas///Patialas///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Patialas & Salwars : Patialas";}}}}}}}}}i:3;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:41:"products.php?la=bags///Bags///Bags///Bags";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:56:"products.php?la=bags&lb=Bags///Bags///Bags///Bags : Bags";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:75:"products.php?la=bags&lb=Bags&lc=Other///Other///Other///Bags : Bags : Other";}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:91:"products.php?la=bags&lb=Bags&lc=Hand-Bags///Hand Bags///Hand Bags///Bags : Bags : Hand Bags";}}}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:112:"products.php?la=bags&lb=Luggage-and-Travel///Luggage and Travel///Luggage and Travel///Bags : Luggage and Travel";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:127:"products.php?la=bags&lb=Luggage-and-Travel&lc=Duffel-Bags///Duffel Bags///Duffel Bags///Bags : Luggage and Travel : Duffel Bags";}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:119:"products.php?la=bags&lb=Luggage-and-Travel&lc=Suitcases///Suitcases///Suitcases///Bags : Luggage and Travel : Suitcases";}}}}}i:4;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:53:"products.php?la=eyewear///Eyewear///Eyewear///Eyewear";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:106:"products.php?la=eyewear&lb=Spectacle-Frame///Spectacle Frame///Spectacle Frame///Eyewear : Spectacle Frame";}}}i:5;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:53:"products.php?la=watches///Watches///Watches///Watches";}i:6;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:69:"products.php?la=jewelleries///Jewelleries///Jewelleries///Jewelleries";s:8:"children";a:4:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:82:"products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Earings///Earings///Earings///Jewelleries : Earings";}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:134:"products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Necklacse-and-Chains///Necklacse and Chains///Necklacse and Chains///Jewelleries : Necklacse and Chains";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:121:"products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Necklacse-and-Chains&lc=Other///Other///Other///Jewelleries : Necklacse and Chains : Other";}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:137:"products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Necklacse-and-Chains&lc=Necklaces///Necklaces///Necklaces///Jewelleries : Necklacse and Chains : Necklaces";}}}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:98:"products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Accessories///Accessories///Accessories///Jewelleries : Accessories";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:115:"products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Accessories&lc=Brooches///Brooches///Brooches///Jewelleries : Accessories : Brooches";}}}i:3;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:82:"products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Anklets///Anklets///Anklets///Jewelleries : Anklets";}}}i:7;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:69:"products.php?la=electronics///Electronics///Electronics///Electronics";s:8:"children";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:134:"products.php?la=electronics&lb=Computer-Peripherals///Computer Peripherals///Computer Peripherals///Electronics : Computer Peripherals";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:133:"products.php?la=electronics&lb=Computer-Peripherals&lc=Printers///Printers///Printers///Electronics : Computer Peripherals : Printers";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:216:"products.php?la=electronics&lb=Computer-Peripherals&lc=Printers&ld=Single-Function-Printer///Single Function Printer///Single Function Printer///Electronics : Computer Peripherals : Printers : Single Function Printer";}}}}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:82:"products.php?la=electronics&lb=Mobiles///Mobiles///Mobiles///Electronics : Mobiles";}}}i:8;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:97:"products.php?la=homenfurnitures///Home And Furnitures///Home And Furnitures///Home And Furnitures";s:8:"children";a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:86:"products.php?la=homenfurnitures&lb=Other///Other///Other///Home And Furnitures : Other";}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:124:"products.php?la=homenfurnitures&lb=Lights-AnD-Lamps///Lights & Lamps///Lights & Lamps///Home And Furnitures : Lights & Lamps";}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";s:152:"products.php?la=homenfurnitures&lb=Dinnerware-AnD-Crockery///Dinnerware & Crockery///Dinnerware & Crockery///Home And Furnitures : Dinnerware & Crockery";s:8:"children";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"id";s:175:"products.php?la=homenfurnitures&lb=Dinnerware-AnD-Crockery&lc=Cups-AnD-Saucers///Cups & Saucers///Cups & Saucers///Home And Furnitures : Dinnerware & Crockery : Cups & Saucers";}}}}}}';

$array_unserl = unserialize($array_seril);

print_r($array_unserel);
```

that will look something like this :

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => about.php
            [otitle] => About Us
            [utitle] => About Us
            [ttip] => About US
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => products.php?la=men
            [otitle] => Men
            [utitle] => Men
            [ttip] => Men
            [children] => Array
                        (
                           [url] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing
                           [otitle] => All Clothing
                           [utitle] => All Clothing
                           [ttip] => Men : All Clothing
                           [children] = > Array
```

How can I achieve this, please help

Please copy the first blue-box code in your php file and run in you server(..local) with **< pre > print_r($array_unserel);**  and you will be able to see the "id" key and the full array clearly

Here is the sample of the original array view

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => about.php///About Us///About Us///About US
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => products.php?la=men///Men///Men///Men
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing///All Clothing///All Clothing///Men : All Clothing
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear///Winter & Seasonal Wear///Winter & Seasonal Wear///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Jackets///Jackets///Jackets///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Jackets
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Thermal-Pants///Thermal Pants///Thermal Pants///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Thermal Pants
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Suits-AnD-Blazers///Suits & Blazers///Suits & Blazers///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Suits & Blazers
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Winter-AnD-Seasonal-Wear&ld=Suits-AnD-Blazers&le=Blazers///Blazers///Blazers///Men : All Clothing : Winter & Seasonal Wear : Suits & Blazers : Blazers
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Other///Other///Other///Men : All Clothing : Other
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Shirts///Shirts///Shirts///Men : All Clothing : Shirts
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Shirts&ld=Formal-Shirts///Formal Shirts///Formal Shirts///Men : All Clothing : Shirts : Formal Shirts
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear///Sports Wear///Sports Wear///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Track-Pants///Track Pants///Track Pants///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Track Pants
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Shorts///Shorts///Shorts///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Shorts
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Shorts&le=Sports///Sports///Sports///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Shorts : Sports
                                                                        )

                                                                    [1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Shorts&le=Other///Other///Other///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Shorts : Other
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=TDaShShirts///T-Shirts///T-Shirts///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : T-Shirts
                                                        )

                                                    [3] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Sports-Wear&ld=Other///Other///Other///Men : All Clothing : Sports Wear : Other
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=All-Clothing&lc=Jeans///Jeans///Jeans///Men : All Clothing : Jeans
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear///Footwear///Footwear///Men : Footwear
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Casual-Shoes///Casual Shoes///Casual Shoes///Men : Footwear : Casual Shoes
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Sports///Sports///Sports///Men : Footwear : Sports
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Sandals-and-Floaters///Sandals and Floaters///Sandals and Floaters///Men : Footwear : Sandals and Floaters
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=men&lb=Footwear&lc=Slippers-and-FlipFlop///Slippers and FlipFlop///Slippers and FlipFlop///Men : Footwear : Slippers and FlipFlop
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => products.php?la=women///Women///Women///Women
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear///Ethnic Wear///Ethnic Wear///Women : Ethnic Wear
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Other///Other///Other///Women : Ethnic Wear : Other
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Kurtas-AnD-Kurties///Kurtas & Kurties///Kurtas & Kurties///Women : Ethnic Wear : Kurtas & Kurties
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Kurtas-AnD-Kurties&ld=Kurties///Kurties///Kurties///Women : Ethnic Wear : Kurtas & Kurties : Kurties
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms///Ethnic Bottoms///Ethnic Bottoms///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Harem-Pants///Harem Pants///Harem Pants///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Harem Pants
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Patialas-AnD-Salwars///Patialas & Salwars///Patialas & Salwars///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Patialas & Salwars
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Patialas-AnD-Salwars&le=Salwars///Salwars///Salwars///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Patialas & Salwars : Salwars
                                                                        )

                                                                    [1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => products.php?la=women&lb=Ethnic-Wear&lc=Ethnic-Bottoms&ld=Patialas-AnD-Salwars&le=Patialas///Patialas///Patialas///Women : Ethnic Wear : Ethnic Bottoms : Patialas & Salwars : Patialas
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => products.php?la=bags///Bags///Bags///Bags
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=bags&lb=Bags///Bags///Bags///Bags : Bags
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=bags&lb=Bags&lc=Other///Other///Other///Bags : Bags : Other
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=bags&lb=Bags&lc=Hand-Bags///Hand Bags///Hand Bags///Bags : Bags : Hand Bags
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=bags&lb=Luggage-and-Travel///Luggage and Travel///Luggage and Travel///Bags : Luggage and Travel
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=bags&lb=Luggage-and-Travel&lc=Duffel-Bags///Duffel Bags///Duffel Bags///Bags : Luggage and Travel : Duffel Bags
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=bags&lb=Luggage-and-Travel&lc=Suitcases///Suitcases///Suitcases///Bags : Luggage and Travel : Suitcases
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => products.php?la=eyewear///Eyewear///Eyewear///Eyewear
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=eyewear&lb=Spectacle-Frame///Spectacle Frame///Spectacle Frame///Eyewear : Spectacle Frame
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => products.php?la=watches///Watches///Watches///Watches
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => products.php?la=jewelleries///Jewelleries///Jewelleries///Jewelleries
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Earings///Earings///Earings///Jewelleries : Earings
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Necklacse-and-Chains///Necklacse and Chains///Necklacse and Chains///Jewelleries : Necklacse and Chains
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Necklacse-and-Chains&lc=Other///Other///Other///Jewelleries : Necklacse and Chains : Other
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Necklacse-and-Chains&lc=Necklaces///Necklaces///Necklaces///Jewelleries : Necklacse and Chains : Necklaces
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Accessories///Accessories///Accessories///Jewelleries : Accessories
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Accessories&lc=Brooches///Brooches///Brooches///Jewelleries : Accessories : Brooches
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => products.php?la=jewelleries&lb=Anklets///Anklets///Anklets///Jewelleries : Anklets
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Please mention your expected result as well.

Comment: What `id` ? There is no `id` in your example

Comment: If you will copy the first block code in your php file and run in you server with <pre>print_r($array_unserel);</pre> you will be able to see the "id" and the full array clearly

Comment: @AnupSurin I suggest putting that result in your question so not everyone looking at this has to run it to have a look what the original looks like.

Comment: @AnupSurin the *result* not instructions. People dont want to run code just to be able to look at a question ^^, as in, run that code yourself, and copypase that output in there. And make it clear that it is the array you are starting with and that the array you have in your question is your desired output

Comment: Hi Olle, But the array is very big if you will will see in the html <pre>

Comment: cut it down to a sample size like you did with that sample output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) to iterate through elements of array and then [explode](http://php.net/explode) to split words:

```
array_walk_recursive($array_unserl, function(&$value, $key) {
    $tempArr = [];
    if($key == "id") {
        list($tempArr['url'],$tempArr['otitle'],$tempArr['utitle'],$tempArr['ttip']) = explode('///', $value);
    }
    $value = $tempArr;
});

print_r($array_unserl);
```

This will replace your `id` key values with exploded content. Something like this:

```
[id] => Array
(
    [url] => about.php
    [otitle] => About Us
    [utitle] => About Us
    [ttip] => About US
)
```

Comment: Hi Thamilan, how would i see the result, can you please explain. I am getting the result as one.

Comment: use same  `print_r($array_unserl);`

Comment: Don't check the returned value of array_walk_recursive (it returns a boolean on success/failure), but your array ;)

Comment: I checked the print_r($array_unserl); is showing me the original array.

Comment: I changed <code>$tempArr = [ ];</code> to <code>$tempArr = array();</code>.

Comment: I saw the link working exactly as I wanted. But not running in my localhost. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' ..

Comment: it might be because you are using older php version. but still, if you use `array()` instead of `[]`it should work.

Comment: Thanks Bro, working cool. Initially I removed the "&" before the $value.